# Определить широковещательный IP-адрес

Tags: сеть, ip, ip-address

Есть IP-адрес 10.40.14.14/17. Есть Маска сети: 255.255.128.0 и IP-адрес сети: 10.40.0.0

Вопрос: Как определить широковещательный адрес сети?

Comment: вообще есть ipcalc https://www.google.ru/search?q=ipcalcА нужен ответ или алгоритм?

Comment: желательно алгоритм

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inkvizitor68sl@malygos:~$ ipcalc 10.40.14.14/17Address:   10.40.14.14          00001010.00101000.0 0001110.00001110Netmask:   255.255.128.0 = 17   11111111.11111111.1 0000000.00000000Wildcard:  0.0.127.255          00000000.00000000.0 1111111.11111111=>Network:   10.40.0.0/17         00001010.00101000.0 0000000.00000000HostMin:   10.40.0.1            00001010.00101000.0 0000000.00000001HostMax:   10.40.127.254        00001010.00101000.0 1111111.11111110**Broadcast: 10.40.127.255        00001010.00101000.0 1111111.11111111**Hosts/Net: 32766
```

http://ip-calculator.ru/ ну или где то здесь

Comment: Если есть трудности с подсчётом вручную, то есть программка LAN-калькулятор. В сети найти не трудно.